# What is $a_{22}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I remember doing this problem in linear algebra where you had to solve for k given the determinant and the rest of the values in the matrix. This problem is a little more complicated.

Two of the three eigenvalues of the following matrix are 8.71 and 3.33. The determinant of the matrix is -436. What is $a_{22}$?

$$
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
        a_{31} & a_{32} & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I just want to make sure my logic for this problem is okay and to get some help with where to go next. Since the determinant does not equal to 0 then the matrix is invertible. It is also a square matrix. So, the determinant is the product of its eigenvalues. With this, I found the third eigenvalue to be -15.03225384. I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: How can the eigenvalues be all positive and the determinant negative?

Comment: Sorry, it should be -15.03225384.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right! The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so you correctly found the third eigenvalue as $-15.0323$.

Now, we also know that the trace (i.e. the sum of the diagonal elements) is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues. Thus $- 2 + a_{22} + 9 = 8.71 + 3.33 - 15.0323$ and we simply solve now to get

> $a_{22} = -9.9925$

Comment: How do you know that the sum of the diagonal elements is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues?

Comment: @ayoshna - I don't remember an exact proof, but it boils down to manipulating the matrix into an upper triangular. These leave the total trace unchanged, while converting the diagonal entries to the eigenvalues. Long story short, I remember that property from my graduate-level matrix theory class (and probably from Linear Algebra as well.

Comment: @Ayoshna By expanding the determinant $$
\operatorname{det} (A - \lambda E) = \begin{vmatrix}a_{11} - \lambda & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & a_{23}\\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} - \lambda\end{vmatrix} = -\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 \operatorname{tr} A + \dots
$$ 
On the other hand
$$
\operatorname{det} (A - \lambda E) = -(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2)(\lambda - \lambda_3) = -\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3) + \dots
$$